# Is there a finite boundariless pseudosphere without edges and vertices?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, curvature, noneuclidean-geometry

A sphere represents finite boundariless surface with constant positive curvature, while a Clifford's torus represents finite boundariless surface with constant zero curvature.

Both of these surfaces have neither edges nor vertices.

Meanwhile, tractricoids, a kind of pseudosphere, represents finite surface with constant negative curvature, but it has ‘sharp’ edges and vertex, along the equator and poles respectively.

Is there a pseudosphere that is both **finite** and **boundariless**, and **having neither edges nor vertices** (like a sphere or Clifford's torus, unlike a tractricoid)?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Yes, there exist smooth, compact surfaces of constant negative Gaussian curvature embedded in a Euclidean space, but not in Euclidean three-space. (I don't know the optimal dimension offhand.)

Comment: Should these surfaces be embedded in some Euclidean space, or are you looking for standalone 2-manifolds with constant negative curvature?

Comment: @Magma it may be embedded in non-Euclidean space, like Clifford's torus is.

Comment: @Prido1024 The Clifford torus is still embedded in 4D euclidean space, I guess you can also consider it embedded in 3D spherical space, but I'm asking about manifolds that aren't embedded anywhere at all.